# Set Single Elements in Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a question regarding a Dictionary of Dictionaries. Is there a shorter way to put single elements in the Dict than I did?

```
var cellHeight = [ Int : [ Int : CGFloat ] ]()

// ...

if let _ = cellHeight[0] {
    cellHeight[0]![2] = 0.0
} else {
    cellHeight[0] = [ 2 : 0.0 ]
}
```

In all the tutorials I checked it's only explained how to fill/initialize the full dict-of-dict and than read from it, but not how to fill it part by part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is basically right. You can be slightly more elegant, like this:

```
let didit = cellHeight[0]?[2] = 0 // yields an Optional<Void>
if didit == nil { // that didn't work, so create the entry
    cellHeight[0] = [2:0]
}
```

And that can be tightened up even further, without the extra variable:

```
if nil == (cellHeight[0]?[2] = 0) {
    cellHeight[0] = [2:0]
}
```

If this is a recurring pattern in your code, you can of course abstract it into a function.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the element. If an entry into a dictionary does not exist yet, adding an element to that key will create one. If a key already exists, then adding an element will overwrite the old one. Reading from a dictionary key that does not exist will return nil.  Reading from a dictionary returns an optional.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because if there are already sub-dictionaries for cellHeight[0] they will be replaced with the new one. This is the reason that I implemented the complicated structure to check if there are already sub-dictionaries and handle it different. see here: [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/ZTHhAtp)